# Set state of a component from another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a stateful component which has a scroll event listener like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import AppDetailPageUI from './AppDetailPageUI.js'


class AppDetailPageSF extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        scrolledDown:false,
    };

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppDetailPageUI

        scrolledDown={this.state.scrolledDown}
      />
    );
  }


   componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll(event)  {

    if (window.scrollY === 0 && this.state.scrolledDown === true) {
      this.setState({scrolledDown: false});
    } 
    else if (window.scrollY !== 0 && this.state.scrolledDown !== true) {
      this.setState({scrolledDown: true});
    }
  }

}

export default withRouter(AppDetailPageSF)
```

This works perfectly fine.But i want to use handleScroll method in many statefull components, and including the same method in every component is not a good practice.

so this is what i tried instead, I created another HandleScrollUtil function something like this

```
const HandleScrollUtil = {
    handleScroll: function(component) {

    if (window.scrollY === 0 && component.state.scrolledDown === true) {
        component.setState({scrolledDown: false});
    } 
    else if (window.scrollY !== 0 && component.state.scrolledDown !== true) {
        component.setState({scrolledDown: true});
    }
  }
}

export default HandleScrollUtil
```

and then i tried calling this method by passing this reference something like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', HandleScrollUtil.handleScroll(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll',  HandleScrollUtil.handleScroll(this));
  }
```

But it does not seem to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only respective `component` can deal with its `state`, you can create handler inside the 
**AppDetailPageSF component** something like

```
setScrollDownHandler = (event,scrollValue) =>{
 this.setState({scrolledDown: scrollValue});
}
```

then you can pass this handler down to any component has a `prop`, this is the right way to it.

Code to update the **State** must be in the same component, all we could do it is create a hander to deal with it and pass that **handler** to places where we would like to update it from.

> Solution is a **Higher Order Component**

I would recommend using a **HOC** like this, it can be wrapped to any component you are going to use.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const withScrollHandler = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class extends Component {

        componentDidMount() {
              this.props.setScrollDownHandler();
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
              this.props.setScrollDownHandler();
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <div>
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default withScrollHandler;
```

Comment: But i can only pass this handler only if there is parent-child relationship between component. I want to have this handleScroll method in many components which has no relationship with one another, so is it a good practice to include the same method in every component as it will lead to duplicate code?